# When maximizing from taskbar Google Chrome not displaying correctly

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate installed PC. My default browser is Google Chrome. Most of the time, when I maximize Chrome from the taskbar it is not displaying correctly. Only a few parts of it can be viewed. I had to either resize or restart it to view properly. No other software in my system have this problem. Why Chrome behaves like this ? Is it solvable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clicking on chrome menu > settings
at the bottom of that page click on "show advanced settings"
at the bottom of that  page "[ ]  Use hardware acceleration when available"is this box ticked? if it is can you untick it and it will help